# Animating GeoJSON paths in D3 + Leaflet

Tags: d3.js, geojson

I'm trying to wrap my head around animating GeoJSON MultiLineString in D3. I've seen some helpful [examples](http://jsfiddle.net/5m35J/6/) from  that involves using Tween Dash-ing of the SVG. At this point, I'm able to draw GeoJSON to the map, but I get lost as to how to work with my paths as SVG so that I can do Tween Dash. ANy help or explanation would be so helpful.

Thanks!

Here is my relevant code:

Data snippet:

```
{"type": "FeatureCollection","features": [ {"type":"Feature","geometry":{"type": "MultiLineString", "coordinates":[[[-74.12706, 40.734680000000004], [-74.12199000000001, 40.73335], [-74.12036, 40.734730000000006], [-74.15457, 40.71811], [-74.18125, 40.71041],...
```

And code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    getData();  

});

var map = new L.Map("map", {center: [40.7127, -74.0059], zoom: 6})
    .addLayer(new L.TileLayer("http://{s}.tile.stamen.com/toner-lite/{z}/{x}/{y}.jpg"));

var svg = d3.select(map.getPanes().overlayPane).append("svg"),
    g = svg.append("g").attr("class", "leaflet-zoom-hide")

function getData(){
    console.log("Called getData()");

    queue()
        .defer(d3.json, '/data/test_lines_linestring.json') 
        .await(makemap)     
}

function makemap(error, data){

    var transform = d3.geo.transform({point: projectPoint});
    var path = d3.geo.path().projection(transform);

    var route = g.selectAll("path")
        .data(data.features)
        .enter()
        .append("path")
        .attr("class", "route")


    var targetPath = d3.selectAll(".route")[0][0]
    var pathNode = d3.select(targetPath).selectAll('path').node();
    console.log(targetPath)
    console.log(pathNode)
```

Logging TargetPath gives me this:

```
<path class="route" d= "M632,352L633,352L633,352L631,353L630,..."></path>
```

Logging PathNode gives me:

```
null
```

**UPDATE**: I'm now getting some sensible data out of my logging, showing a path length. I'm now following ([this](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/5649592)) example to animate the path. I feel like I'm very close, but again, any help would be much appreciated. My updated code is in this gist here ---> [gist](https://gist.github.com/bdkauff/98493089dae8d98950b2)

**UPDATE 2**: I'm able to draw my data to the map in a static manner. Gist of my updated code is [here](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/bf7915d2f8e475eaeb70). NB: the tween-dash animation functions are not being called. Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

Your `.selectAll` is executed on `targetPath`, which is already a selection of a `path`.

When you select the first item in the first item of a selection (like `d3.selectAll(".route")[0][0]`) you're doing the same thing that `.node()` does, which is to give you the element associated with the selection. So:

```
 d3.selectAll(".route")[0][0]
```

..is the same as:

```
 d3.selectAll(".route").node()
```

Your code, then, is trying to give you the element associated with any path elements that are children of your selected `path`, of which there are none.

You should try to avoid using `.node()` with `selectAll`, since it will give you the first element in a selection, but your selection may consist of multiple elements (and `.node()` will only return one element). So, it's not wrong, but it might have behavior you don't expect.

Comment: Thanks! Your comment got me thinking about this in a better way. I think I'm really close. See my amended status above.